# Sign xml request using non exportable private key from etoken c#

Tags: c#

I am working with digital signature. We have to generate xml request and sign the request using private key. The private key to be taken from etoken which is non exportable. My findings showed that private key cannot be extracted when it is marked as non exportable. In this case, how can I sign the xml request. Please help.

Comment: Which findings, exactly? I'm not 100% sure but I don't think this is correct. You do need the privileges to access the priv key, so maybe run VS as administrator? You can check the access rights with the certs tool.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I have privileges to access my private key but was not sure how to use it through C# to sign xml request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Took a while as the requirement was bit rare. This link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240655/Using-a-Smart-Card-Certificate-with-NET-Security-i helped me to get the solution. Please refer to below code. For SignXml() method, please refer this msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

        // find cert by thumbprint
        var foundCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.Thumbprint, "12345", true);

        if (foundCerts.Count == 0)
            return;

        var certForSigning = foundCerts[0];
        store.Close();

        // prepare password
        var pass = new SecureString();
        var passwordstring = "password";

        var chararr = passwordstring.ToCharArray();
        foreach (var i in chararr)
            pass.AppendChar(i);
        // take private key
        var privateKey = certForSigning.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        // make new CSP parameters based on parameters from current private key but throw in password
        CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(1,
             privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
             privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
             new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(),
             pass);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
        // Sign the XML document. 
        SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaCryptoServiceProvider);
```